# Rails console: NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I just added a new model to my app named Collector.

I'm trying to make some data changes using the console on my server:

```
GsCollector.all.each do |gsc|
  coll = Collector.new
  coll.project_id = gsc.project_id
  coll.kind = 'GsCollector'
  coll.optional = gsc.optional
  coll.included = gsc.included
  coll.save
  gsc.collector_id = coll.id
  gsc.save

  gsc.custom_descriptions.each do |cd|
    cd.collector_id = coll.id
    cd.save
  end

  gsc.order_notes.each do |note|
    note.collector_id = coll.id
    note.save
  end
end
```

But this fails with:

```
GsCollector Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `gs_collectors`.* FROM `gs_collectors` 
NameError: uninitialized constant Collector
    from (irb):2:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):1:in `each'
    from (irb):1
```

What's wrong here?  These commands in the console on my dev machine worked fine.  I did migrate the database on the server.

Comment: Are you using irb or the rails console command?

Comment: rails console production

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run the The command

```
reload!
```

Or restart your terminals to get good result